# Debian: Get single IPv6 over DHCP with Prefix Delegation

Tags: debian, ipv6, dhcpv6

I've a Debian 9 server with multiple network interfaces acting as web server connected to an ISP-provided optical network terminal (ONT) @ 1Gbps. The ISP provides us with multiple dynamic IPv4 addresses and optional static addresses.

Currently we're using a single static IPv4 address set at `\etc\network\interfaces` as:

```
 iface eth0 inet static
   address 89.xxx.xxx.xxx
   gateway 89.xxx.xxx.xxx
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

With IPv6 they are not proving static options yet and they **dynamically assign IPv6 blocks via prefix delegation using DHCP**. The prefix length is `/56` .

**How can get one single IPv6 address on the network interface?** I believe the server has to request a block and then assign the first IP to itself (or some random IP).

I've tried a simple config `\etc\network\interfaces` as:

```
iface eth0 inet6 dhcp
  request_prefix 1
  accept_ra 2
```

`/etc/sysctl.conf` with:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=2
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=2
```

But it didn't work, I just got a local link IPv6. Then I tried `wide-dhcpv6`:

```
interface eth0{
  send ia-na 0;
  send rapid-commit;
  request domain-name-servers;
  script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};

id-assoc na 0 {
};
```

Still only getting local link. From my understanding `id-assoc na 0` would request an IPv6... however how this works since the ISP only provides everything as `/56` block?

I also tried this without any luck:

```
interface eth0 {
    send ia-na 0;
    send ia-pd 0;
    send rapid-commit;
    request domain-name-servers;
    script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};

id-assoc na 0 { 

};

id-assoc pd 0 {
    prefix ::/56 infinity;
    prefix-interface eth0 {
        sla-len 8;
        sla-id 0;
        ifid 1;
    };
};
```

**My final questions**:

1. What should `\etc\network\interfaces` look like when using `wide-dhcpv6`?
2. Is any of my `wide-dhcpv6` configurations correct?
3. It is possible to get the IPv6 without `wide-dhcpv6`, using just the Debian dhcp client?
4. ISP uses `rapid-commit` how can I enable that in `\etc\network\interfaces`?

---

**Note**: one of my colleagues was under the impression that IPv6 was just not working, so we tried to connect a DD-WRT router to the ISP and we set its settings as:

[image]

**After a reboot we got IPv6 on the router** and on the computers connect to it, **so the issue must be with the configuration of our Debian server**.

[image]

Comment: It's not a bug... It's a FEATURE! Try to ping your server/router over IPv6 and just omit the CIDR subnet notation (`/56`), you'll see it works (if no firewall blocks ICMP traffic). It's normal that you get a whole subnet. If your clients can't connect via IPv6 to the internet, maybe the DHCP is misconfigured or routing isn't set up. I'd suggest you read up a bit on IPv6, here is a blog post I found: https://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/set-up-ipv6-lan-with-linux

Comment: @NoMad thanks for the answer, I didn't make myself clear, sorry. What we are looking for: connect the server directly to the ISP (nothing in between), ask for the `/56` prefix and assign at least ONE IP on that to our server. We don't need the server to provide DHCP to a local network nor make it a gateway. It's just a web server that needs to assign IPv6 addressees to websites.

Comment: Common desktop and server Linux distributions don't yet have good support for DHCPv6 prefix delegation. If possible you should continue to use the embedded router.